# Camel route using spring-ws client occasionally failes to marshal jaxb

Tags: java, spring, jaxb, apache-camel

I've a camel route that occasionally failes with:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceTransformerException: Transformation error: Can't transform a Source of type javax.xml.transform.stax.StAXSource; nested exception is javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Can't transform a Source of type javax.xml.transform.stax.StAXSource
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:610) ~[spring-ws-core-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:539) ~[spring-ws-core-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:494) ~[spring-ws-core-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:481) ~[spring-ws-core-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.apache.camel.component.spring.ws.SpringWebserviceProducer.process(SpringWebserviceProducer.java:87) ~[camel-spring-ws-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
```

The route is longer, but this is the core snippet with the jaxb marshalling:

`from("direct:ins").routeId("ARCHIVING_CHAT")
                .setHeader("chat", body())
                .to("bean:convertChatToRequest?method=createSaveObjectRequest")
                .marshal(jaxb)
                .to("log:eAarkivA2A_REQUEST?level=INFO")
                .beanRef("archivingSlip")
                .to("bean:checkResponse")`

and from camel-config.xml:

```
<bean id="baseCamelMarshallerWSTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate" scope="prototype">
        <constructor-arg ref="messageFactory" />
        <property name="checkConnectionForError" value="true"/>
        <!--<property name="transformerFactory" value="com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl"/>-->
        <property name="transformerFactoryClass" value="org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl"/>
        <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller" />
        <property name="unmarshaller" ref="marshaller" />
    </bean>
```

Most of the time this is working perfectly. Only occasionally it fails after restart of the camel-service. When it failes all the traffic through the route failes. This randomness is useless for production where the servers are scheduled to reboot.

I've looked at this but with no help: [Camel route using spring-ws client occasionally throws javax.xml.transform.stax.StAXSource exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530533/camel-route-using-spring-ws-client-occasionally-throws-javax-xml-transform-stax)

Any ideas what I should be looking for to making sure this never happens? Thx.

Comment: Are you using Karaf 4?

Comment: Since you say this happens only occasionally, are you sure this has nothing to do with the data being sent? Why not add debug level logs and print the body as well to see what is different when it fails.

Comment: It cannot be the data, because after restart the jaxb transformation is processing successfully the same data when the route failed.